# Connect [Authorize] with custom database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorize-attribute

How do I order the [Authorize] attribute to connect to my own `Roles` database to check for specifics roles in there?

**What I know**:

- I have to create a class that inherits from `AuthorizeAttribute`.

**What I don't know**:

- What to write inside my custom class in the way that `[CustomAuthorize(Roles: "Administrator")]` checks if the current user has that role.

Please, I really need help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `AuthorizeCore()` method and return true or false.

Comment: So I just need to check for record in the database and return `true` or `false`? And how I do to redirect to the default action, the `Login` action, when the authentication fails?

Comment: @Federico: The base class does that for you.  https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs

Comment: And how do the base class know where to get the current `User`? Is it in the `httpContext`?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a custom RoleProvider to work with the ASP.NET Identification.

Comment: I rather create my own `Membership Provider`, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: That link is for customizing a `Role Provider`, any reference for creating custom `User Provider`?